# Drupal 8 email filtering

Tags: php, drupal

- I have the Registration Validation module installed, which works great for anything after the @ sign. But I also need to filter before the domain.
- I've tried using the User Restrictions module, but it doesn't seem to work at all.
- Perhaps I'm aiming in the wrong direction, but essentially I want to add regex to the email field when an anonymous user attempts to create an account. For example, firstname.lastname@example.com is allowed, but 123abc@example.com is not.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to this but I did it on the JavaScript end with their RegEx Objects. An example program is here https://github.com/webdevtrev/JavaScript-RegEx

Comment: Javascript is not a good solution as it is very unlikely to stop bots registering an account.

Comment: I agree, it can be cool to do it in Javascript but you need a server side check.

Answer (score 0):

I made a [module for D7](https://www.drupal.org/project/regex_reg_deny) years ago that did this.
But I have not made a D8 version. You could adapt the code to D8.

Here are a couple of options that may work for you, though I have not tried them.
[Field validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_validation) <-- this one looks like what you want, ie regex.
[User restrictions](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_restrictions)

Comment: I've tried both Field validation, and User restrictions. I couldnt find a way to add field validation to the user registration form. And user restrictions just straight up doesnt seem to work :( I'll attempt to update your code, but it may be beyond my current understanding.

Answer (score 0):

In a [custom module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules), you can either:

- use the [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.2.x) in your case `hook_form_user_register_form_alter()` to add a validate function to the form and check if the value of the mail field is good or not,
- or you can [add a constraint](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/entity-validation-api/providing-a-custom-validation-constraint) to the user's email field.

And to validate your mail format you'll need to use a PHP regex with [preg_match()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Comment: I've been playing around with this and attempting to create my own module. I'm finding it pretty difficult, but I am learning lots. Thank you for your response.